# Laptop fails to wake up from suspend (boots instead) [Xubuntu 16.04.03]

Tags: xubuntu, suspend

When I suspend my laptop (ASUS N550JV) by closing lid or via menu, it seems to be suspended but when pressing any key on the keyboard, it fails to wake up again and regular boot screen pops up (instead of resuming previous session).

- power manager is set up to suspend in all cases
- there are two BIOS options that might affect this issue:

  - Power off energy saving - disabled
  - Wake on lid open - enabled
- I use Nouveau graphic drivers

Comment: did you try enabling Energy saving?

Comment: Yes, I think that was enabled by default. But the description clearly states, that it cuts the power off trying to save energy when not active or something like that. I will try again to be sure.

Comment: Now I am sure. Didn't help, I've disabled it again.

Comment: Well, it looks like a hardware / BIOS problem. Cannot wake from suspend in Windows neither.